# How to mask a email id without masking its domain name and the dots in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have multiple email ids in a table. But I need mask all the email ids using oracle SQL. Below are some examples of masking email ids,

Input : Output :

1. `alex.hales@gmail.com` = `****.hales@*****.com`
2. `Joeroot.eng@yahoo.co.in` = `*****ot.eng@*****.**.in`

I want to:

First Part:

For each email ids first 5 charters from the left hand side of `@` should be masked with `*`, but if a `.` is coming within the first character then it should not be masked it will remain same.

Second Part:

right hand side from `@` will be masked with `*`, again if a `.` is there then it will remain same and the domain name like `.com`, `.in` should be as is.

**I have tried:**

```
enter code here

Declare
v_id Varchar2(100):= 'abc.defghijklmnop@qrst.uv.wxyz';
v_id1 Varchar2(100);
v_id2 Varchar2(100);
v_id3 Varchar2(100);
v_id4 Varchar2(100);
v_id5 Varchar2(100);
v_id6 Varchar2(100);

Begin
Select v_id,
instr(v_id,'.'),
instr(v_id,'@'),
Case When instr(v_id,'.') >=6
   Then '*****'|| substr(v_id,6,(instr(v_id,'@')-5))
Else
rpad(lpad('.',instr(v_id,'.'),'*'),6,'*') || substr(v_id,7,(instr(v_id,'@')- 6))
End testing
Into v_id1,v_id2,v_id3,v_id4
From dual;

dbms_output.put_line(v_id1);
dbms_output.put_line(v_id2);
dbms_output.put_line(v_id3);
dbms_output.put_line(v_id4);
End;

o/p:::
abc.defghijklmnop@qrst.uv.wxyz. 
4
18
***.**fghijklmnop@


SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (substr(instr('abc.defghijklmnop@qrstname.uv.wxyz','@')+1),'^[.].'*')
FROM dual;

Output:
abc.defghijklmnop@****.**.****
```

I am not able to unmasked the domain name as well as unable to do the whole thing together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for something like [Oracle Data Masking and Subsetting](https://www.oracle.com/database/data-masking-subsetting/index.html).

---

Using only text operations:

```
WITH test_data AS 
(
        SELECT 'alex.hales@gmail.com' AS email FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Joeroot.eng@yahoo.co.in' FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 't.e.s.t.ex.ampl.e@do.ma.i.com' FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 't1@z.a' FROM dual
)
SELECT z.email,
    CASE WHEN INSTR(part1_masked, '*',1, 5) > 0 
          THEN SUBSTR(part1_masked,1,INSTR(part1_masked, '*',1, 5)) 
               || SUBSTR(part1, INSTR(part1_masked, '*',1, 5)+1)
            ELSE part1_masked
    END || '@' 
    || SUBSTR(part2_masked,1,INSTR(part2_masked, '.',-1)-1)
    || SUBSTR(part2,INSTR(part2, '.',-1,1)) AS masked_email 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      email
     ,SUBSTR(t.email, 1, INSTR(t.email, '@')-1) AS part1
     ,SUBSTR(t.email,INSTR(t.email, '@')+1) AS part2
     ,regexp_replace(SUBSTR(t.email, 1, INSTR(t.email, '@')-1),
                            '[[:alnum:]]', '*') AS part1_masked
     ,regexp_replace(SUBSTR(t.email,INSTR(t.email, '@')+1),
                            '[[:alnum:]]', '*') AS part2_masked
    FROM test_data t    
) z
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/WHYZW57050)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╗
║             EMAIL             ║         MASKED_EMAIL          ║
╠═══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ alex.hales@gmail.com          ║ ****.*ales@*****.com          ║
║ Joeroot.eng@yahoo.co.in       ║ *****ot.eng@*****.**.in       ║
║ t.e.s.t.ex.ampl.e@do.ma.i.com ║ *.*.*.*.*x.ampl.e@**.**.*.com ║
║ t1@z.a                        ║ **@*.*                        ║
╚═══════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╝
```

How it works:

1. `SUBSTR(t.email, 1, INSTR(t.email, '@')-1) AS part1` - split email (`@` is delimiter)
2. `regexp_replace(SUBSTR(t.email, 1, INSTR(t.email, '@')-1),    '[[:alnum:]]', '*') AS part1_masked` - replace all alfanumeric characters with `*`
3. `INSTR(part1_masked, '*',1, 5) > 0` - check if exists at least 5 `*` in masked string
4. Concatenate part up to 5 stars from masked string and the rest from unmasked

### EDIT:

```
WITH test_data AS 
(
        SELECT 'alex.hales@gmail.com' AS email FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Joeroot.eng@yahoo.co.in' FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 't.e.s.t.ex.ampl.e@do.ma.i.com' FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 't1@z.a' FROM dual
)
SELECT z.email,
     CASE WHEN INSTR(part1, '.')-1 < 0 THEN part1_masked
          WHEN INSTR(part1, '.')-1 <=5 
          THEN SUBSTR(part1_masked,1, INSTR(part1, '.')) 
               || SUBSTR(part1, INSTR(part1, '.')+1)
           ELSE SUBSTR(part1_masked, 1, 5) || SUBSTR(part1, 6)
      END
    || '@' 
    || SUBSTR(part2_masked,1,INSTR(part2_masked, '.',-1)-1)
    || SUBSTR(part2,INSTR(part2, '.',-1,1)) AS masked_email 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      email
     ,SUBSTR(t.email, 1, INSTR(t.email, '@')-1) AS part1
     ,SUBSTR(t.email,INSTR(t.email, '@')+1) AS part2
     ,regexp_replace(SUBSTR(t.email, 1, INSTR(t.email, '@')-1),
                            '[[:alnum:]]', '*') AS part1_masked
     ,regexp_replace(SUBSTR(t.email,INSTR(t.email, '@')+1),
                            '[[:alnum:]]', '*') AS part2_masked
    FROM test_data t    
) z
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/QSXIZ73522)**</kbd>

Ouptut:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╗
║             EMAIL             ║         MASKED_EMAIL          ║
╠═══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╣
║ alex.hales@gmail.com          ║ ****.hales@*****.com          ║
║ Joeroot.eng@yahoo.co.in       ║ *****ot.eng@*****.**.in       ║
║ t.e.s.t.ex.ampl.e@do.ma.i.com ║ *.e.s.t.ex.ampl.e@**.**.*.com ║
║ t1@z.a                        ║ **@*.a                        ║
╚═══════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╝
```